# IE Keyboard focus being stolen in popup window

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, facebook

I have a Flash application that integrated Facebook friend connect. When the user initiates Facebook Friend Connect it pops up a new window that prompts the user to log into facebook.

On internet explorer when I type in my username and password I intermittently lose key strokes. If I remove the flash page from the HTML content and do the same facebook connect on IE I don't lose the keystrokes.

On Firefox this works completely fine.

Is there something in flash that could be causing this behavior of intermittent keyboard focus stealing on IE?

Comment: can you provide a link for the application ??